# Avoid Parameter Binding When Executing Query with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, binding, sqlalchemy, teradata, executequery

I am using SQLALchemy to execute queries on Teradata. One of the queries I execute is a DDL statement to replace a stored procedure:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE DEV_MIGRATION_TOOL.UNIT_TEST_NEW_STORED_PROCEDURE()
UNIT_TEST_NEW_STORED_PROCEDURE:
BEGIN
    DECLARE V_VAR VARCHAR(50);
    SELECT 'Hello World!'
    INTO :V_VAR;
END;
```

This SQL statement is assigned to a variable `query` and is executed by SQLALchemy with the session execute method:

```
def execute_sql_statement(self, query):
    """Generic method to execute a SQL statement on target environment."""
    self.target_environment.db_session.execute(query)
    self.target_environment.db_session.commit()
```

The problem I have it that SQLAlchemy assumes the `:V_VAR` variable is a parameter which should be supplied with a dictionary. See documentation here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.execute

```
result = session.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=:param", {"param":5})
```

In the current configuration, it triggers the error message:

> 2018-04-18 19:09:27,874 - migration_script - INFO - Execute object DDL
>   statement on UAT environment. 2018-04-18 19:09:27,875 -
>   migration_script - ERROR - (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) **A
>   value is required for bind parameter 'V_VAR'** [SQL:
>   "()\rUNIT_TEST_NEW_STORED_PROCEDURE:\rBEGIN\r    DECLARE V_VAR
>   VARCHAR(50);\r    SELECT 'Hello World!'\r    INTO ?;\rEND;"]
>   [parameters: [{}]]

Would you know a way to avoid this error message so that my DDL statement above is executed without error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Session.execute()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.execute) interprets plain SQL strings as if passed in a [`text()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) construct. Due to that you have to escape any colons that you do not want interpreted as beginning a placeholder:

> For SQL statements where a colon is required verbatim, as within an inline string, use a backslash to escape

So your DDL statement `query` should be:

```
"""
REPLACE PROCEDURE DEV_MIGRATION_TOOL.UNIT_TEST_NEW_STORED_PROCEDURE()
UNIT_TEST_NEW_STORED_PROCEDURE:
BEGIN
    DECLARE V_VAR VARCHAR(50);
    SELECT 'Hello World!'
    INTO \\:V_VAR;
END;
"""
```

<sup>Note that the backslash is properly escaped on purpose. Newer versions of Python will produce `SyntaxWarning`s for invalid escape sequences such as `"\:"`, if not using raw string literals.</sup>