# Executing Truly Raw SQL in SQLAlchemy in Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have data I'm loading into PostgreSQL with SQLAlchemy Core. The data is in SQL. It contains JSON which looks like the param syntax in SQLAlchemy, i.e. `:foo`.

How do I execute the SQL in a way that's truly raw, i.e. with no parsing of its contents for params or anything else?

Alternately, how do I escape the string to get the literals into PostgreSQL around the SQLAlchemy `text()` parser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid Parameter Binding When Executing Query with SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49902843/avoid-parameter-binding-when-executing-query-with-sqlalchemy)

Comment: Please include a sample of the SQL you're trying to execute, and how you're executing it.